# Linked server not working after AWS RDS failover

Tags: amazon-rds, linked-server

Linked servers created on AWS RDS to other instances is not working after RDS instance failover. Error we get is "An error occurred during decryption".

This is similar issue reported, but no solution offered.
[Linked Server: An error occurred during decryption](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/255126/linked-server-an-error-occurred-during-decryption)

Any help if this is a bug or limitation with RDS?

Answer (score 1):

**Update: July 2020**

As of July 2020, we now replicate the service master key after a host replacement. Previously, during a host replacement linked servers with passwords would get the error “An error occurred during decryption”. This is now resolved.

**Found the answer here**

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/implement-linked-servers-with-amazon-rds-for-microsoft-sql-server/

If a host replacement happens, RDS SQL Server does not restore the service master key. This means that linked servers with passwords will get the error “An error occurred during decryption” when you try to use the linked server. Unfortunately, there is no current notification of a host replacement. The closest you can come is to monitor reboots and failovers via SNS events. You can read more about subscribing to those events on Using Amazon RDS Event Notification. When a reboot or failover happens, you need to manually re-add the linked server login passwords. This is a temporary workaround until a future update to RDS SQL Server addresses this by restoring the service master key after a host replacement.